# JavaScript error in jquery.min.js

Tags: bug, status-completed

[This page](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/10610/game-asset-storage-graphics-3d-models-sounds/10613#10613) (and apparently only this page, but I'm not sure why) has a JavaScript error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

I'm seeing this in the JavaScript Console Chrome 11.0.696.28 beta in OSX. It is of course stopping all JavaScript on the page, preventing me from commenting or doing anything.

Comment: Huh. A couple other sites are actually claiming this same issue. Thus far it's been seen on Super User, Gaming, and Skeptics - each only on a single page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [was examined and resolved by balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85884/add-comment-flag-delete-links-are-broken/85895#85895). I'll quote his answer here:

> This is fixed now.
>
> It took a whole lot of single-stepping through callback after callback after callback, but in the end, it was actually a bug in the HTML code.
>
> When you link directly to an answer (instead of just a question), this answer is shown in a highlight color which then fades back to normal (as everybody has probably seen).
>
> We're in the process of converting our pages from the old ASPX view engine to [Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx), and in the process of converting the partial view that shows a single answer (this conversion happened today), there was a little too much encoding happening, so the result for the highlighted answer looked like this:
>
> ```
> <div id="answer-85877" class="answer" style=&quot;background-color:#F6F5EE;&quot;>
> ```
>
> This is obviously anything but valid (but it actually depends on the browser how it gets handled). When the jQuery color animation plugin tried to find the *current* color, all it found was either garbage or nothing (depending on the browser). When it found nothing, this worked fine (except that you didn't see the animation); when it found garbage, this caused the code to throw up.